# Displaying text from a text file in html

Tags: html

so i have a program that runs on a raspberry pi and outputs data to a text file. I'm wanting to try and display these outputs on a website i have already made.

so the goal is to have a text file (outputs.txt) and have the content from the text file be displayed on the website in the (outputs.txt(the text from the file)) tags

im going to be frank this probably makes no sense and made it even more confusing

Comment: HTML can't do this on its own. You'll need to use Javascript (or a server-side language) to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html can't load any text file alone you need some server side language like php,java.net or javascript.In Php its very easy

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

This will print the content of the file.

Comment: w3 school tutorial for python how to read files :
https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_file_open